# Best Way For Data-Driven non-bone Key Frame Animation?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I am making ios game using cocos2d-x (version on 2.1rc0-x-2.1.3), now stuck on Key Frame Animation problem:

Here is my problem's detail: Currently We just need key frame animation in games(simple,no bones),but in cocos2d-x, the animation is a bit of too simple: when make animation, I have to load several separate images, to code the animation process manually, like animation example code:

```
 CCAnimation *animation = CCAnimation::create();
 for (int i = 1; i < 15; i++)
 {
  char szImageFileName[128] = {0};
  sprintf(szImageFileName, "Images/grossini_dance_%02d.png", i);
  animation->addSpriteFrameWithFileName(szImageFileName);  
 }
CCAnimate *action = CCAnimate::create(animation);
sprite->runAction(action);
```

It really sucks...then I make a deep search, found that cocosBuilder may do this job,and there have two kickstarer projects may support my request:

1 Spriter:
this tool can easily create key frame animation(with bone or not, really simple to use!!), and it can export animation data into a self-made (.scml)XML format,*But it has a big weak spot!!* is it has no offical cocos2d-x runtime support, some developers has made their code, but all buggy and lack of docs.

2 "Cocos-builder": 
It's a shame not found cocos-builder has this kind of function(mainly because I currently do not have a Mac, still working on windows),It seems can edit key frame sprites and export to .ccb files, and I see cocos2d-x has code support for it(like CCBAnimationManager etc. I do not read the code in details..)

3 "Spine": 
It's a great tool,much same like Spriter it has power functions export animation data into jason file and most important is!!: it has fully cocos2d-x runtime support.But this tool is a little bit hard to get hands on(I have to read its doc to know how to add a key frame, and now still trying to figure out how to create "not-bone type" key frame animation)

Is there anyone can give us some guide to choose the best way for Data-Driven non-bone Key Frame Animation?

Any helps will be appericated.

UPDATE:After a little ask in Spine forum,I found out the solution(Spine does support in a hidden way). So now Spine are our choice.

Best Regards,
Frank Cheng

Comment: You like Spine, it seems to di what you need, then just take the time to learn it. The only tool missing from the list with animation support is Levelhelper.

Comment: thank you!I will take a look at Level Helper